# Python time - kernel reports TIME_ERROR: 0x41: Clock Unsynchronized

Tags: google-compute-engine, gcloud

I'm running a Python app on Google Compute Engine that is dependent on `time.sleep` and I keep getting an error on start up of `kernel reports TIME_ERROR: 0x41: Clock Unsynchronized` at which point the app stops running. What's causing this?

Answer (score 0):

I changed my machine image to `--image=debian-8` and it seems to be working again and I'm no longer getting this error, but this is pretty dumb, can someone from the GCloud team look into this? I wasted several hours trying to troubleshoot this. Seems there is something wrong with the `debian-9` image